# how to handle the states of an object

Tags: php, oop

What would be the correct way to handle the types of state that an object can have in an application?

For example, if i have an AcceptanceCriteria class, i need to verify if it is accepted, rejected or pending.

I usually do it by returning numbers that represent the state, but it does not seem like a good form, it can be confusing.

for example:

```
class AcceptanceCriteria
{

const PENDING = 0;
const ACCEPTED = 1;
const REJECTED = 2;

protected $state = self::PENDING;

public function accept():void
{
    $this->state = self::ACCEPTED;
}

public function reject():void
{
    $this->state = self::REJECTED;
}

public function state():int
{
    return $this->state;
}
}
```

I need to check the state frequently and also show it in the front, what is a better way to do it? I dont want to check in the front if and acceptance criteria state is 0, 1 or 2 for do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some accessors that return booleans rather than ints so your algorithm is completely encapsulated?

```
class AcceptanceCriteria
{

const PENDING = 0;
const ACCEPTED = 1;
const REJECTED = 2;

protected $state = self::PENDING;

public function accept():void
{
    $this->state = self::ACCEPTED;
}

public function reject():void
{
    $this->state = self::REJECTED;
}

// Accessors

public function is_rejected():bool
{
    return self::PENDING == $this->state;
}

public function is_accepted():bool
{
    return self::ACCEPTED == $this->state;
}

public function is_rejected():bool
{
    return self::REJECTED == $this->state;
}
```

}

Comment: yes, is a better way to do it, but what happen if the class have more types of the states? inRevision, canceled, or something like this. Should in these case have a lot of accessors for the class?

Comment: Perhaps it could seem like it is getting bloated, but that is why you have a state management class. I worry about readability and maintainability more than the size of the class. `if ( $state->is_accepted() ) { do_something(); }` is really readable, and a class full of one line functions like this is easy to maintain even without comments.

Comment: I agree with what you say, it is much more readable, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Its good way to use strongly typed `enums`. You can use [splEnum](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php) or smart implementation from [My C-Labs](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum).

First move your states to separated enum class

```
<?php
use MyCLabs\Enum\Enum;

class AcceptanceCriteriaStateEnum extends Enum
{
    private const PENDING = 0;
    private const ACCEPTED = 1;
    private const REJECTED = 2;
}
```

then you can modify your class like bellow

```
class AcceptanceCriteria
{
    protected $state = AcceptanceCriteriaStateEnum::PENDING;

    public function setState(AcceptanceCriteriaStateEnum $state):void
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function getState():int
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function isInState(AcceptanceCriteriaStateEnum $checkState):bool
    {
        return $this->state == $checkState;
    }
}
```

for checking state you can use method `isInState` which return boolean

```
$obj = new AcceptanceCriteria();
$obj->setState(AcceptanceCriteriaStateEnum::ACCEPTED);

// check status
echo $obj->isInState(AcceptanceCriteriaStateEnum::ACCEPTED);
```